# Filtering an object field in Unity Editor Extension

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm looking to use Unity's ObjectField to have users search for objects of a particular type. I know the constructor allows for a `typeOf(objectType)`, but that does not seem to allow for filtering on custom components.

Essentially, a previous editor script I have sets up objects, and places a unique custom script on each of the components, but I've been unsuccessful in utilizing the ObjectField to search for just those objects. If I change the `typeOf` in my object field to be my component, it is always empty, despite there being many prefabs with that script attached in my project.

Has anyone had any success with this? Using `GameObject` finds them, but this finds all game objects. Is there any way to restrict this? Or to keep it only looking at particular folders?

Comment: Can you include the code related to `GameObject` that works, and an example of what the stuff with the custom scripts looks like? An expensive method would be to get all `GameObjets` and call `GetComponent<>()` on them with the name of attached script. If that returns `null` they don't have them and you can discard them. But that feels like a huge waste.

Comment: I would love to know how to do this as well. Something like EditorGUILayout.ObjectField<MyComponentType>( ... ); would be FANTASTIC!

Comment: Same question on unity answers https://answers.unity.com/questions/1296891/possible-to-extend-objectfield-or-override-the-dia.html

Answer (score 2):

Adding a filter while the field itself stays as type Object is a bit tricky. Here's one way.

## Use ShowObjectPicker

Try opening a custom ObjectPicker. To do so you'll have to hide the default object picker and call one with a set searchFilter. It is quite a bit of work.

#### Setting searchFilter

Use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUIUtility.ShowObjectPicker.html with a searchFilter that matches the component you add to every object you want to show up in an ObjectPicker. for example `"t:objectType"`.

There's some good information on using ShowObjectPicker at https://answers.unity.com/questions/554012/how-do-i-use-editorguiutilityshowobjectpicker-c.html

#### Hide default object picker

Here's a post with a way to hide the default object picker [Is there any way to hide the "Object picker" of an EditorGUILayout.ObjectField in Unity Isnpector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397407/is-there-any-way-to-hide-the-object-picker-of-an-editorguilayout-objectfield-i)

#### Show picker

You'll need to create your own Editor GUI.Button to bring up the ShowObjectPicker with the custom searchFilter.

#### Assets searchFilter

As a sidenote, to do the same with file assets use a "l:labelName" fileFilter instead of "t:objectType". You can set the label with the Unity Editor UI as shown here: [image]

or with "ref:relative/path/from/assets/to/material/material.mat"