# Hiding the "Object Picker" of an EditorGUILayout.ObjectField in Unity Inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, customization, unity-editor

I'm just asking if there is any possibility to hide the "Object Picker" (The little knob/menu next to an [ObjectField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.ObjectField.html)) in a custom Inspector. I have some cases where changes are disabled (DisableGroup) and I would like to also hide the knob while the content can not be changed anyway.

[image]

Also to make things easier for users I think about making the field higher (`EditorGUIUtility.SingleLineHeight * 2`) -> the picker gets stretched as well what looks kind of shitty ^^

example:

```c#
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bla : MonoBehaviour {

    [CustomEditor(typeof(Bla))]
    public class BlaEditor : Editor
    {
        private AudioClip _clip;

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
            // do some magic to hide the object picker
            _clip = (AudioClip) EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("some label", _clip, typeof(AudioClip), false);
            EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to stick with an `ObjectField` rather than a simple Label for two reasons:

- Even on a disabled `ObjectField| the "ping" functionality is still working. (If you click on it, the according asset gets highlighted in the Hierarchy.) This is not the case obviously with a label.
- The user should not get confused with completely different looking controls but I rather only want to remove some unnecessary clutter.

Comment: What is your custom editor code?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone well it has about 2000 lines ;) But please see my updated question with my own example

Comment: Well, if you don't want it to me editable at all, you should change the property field for a simple label field with the name of the component

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues sorry I didn't specify this in my question before but I want it to remain an object field for two reasons: 1. While it is editable it is an object field =>The user should not get confused with the controls looking different.  2. Using just a label would remove the "ping" functionality. Even on a disabled object field you can still click it => the according asset gets highlighted in the Hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find a solution to hide the object picker by usage of stylesheets.

If all you want is just to *display* some reference, you can use a simple button basically styled as text field, adding an image and ping the object from code yourself.

```c#
using UnityEngine;

namespace Test
{
    public class TestBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private bool _audioEnabled;
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip _audioClip;
    }
}
```

editor:

```c#
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.UIElements;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Test
{
    [CustomEditor(typeof(TestBehaviour))]
    public class TestBehaviourEditor : Editor
    {
        private SerializedProperty _clipProp;
        private SerializedProperty _audioEnabledProp;
        private ObjectField m_ObjectField;

        private const BindingFlags FIELD_BINDING_FLAGS = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            _clipProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("_audioClip");
            _audioEnabledProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("_audioEnabled");
        }

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            serializedObject.Update();

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_audioEnabledProp);

            if(_audioEnabledProp.boolValue)
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_clipProp);
            else
            {
                //TODO: calculate proper layout 

                var type = target.GetType().GetField(_clipProp.propertyPath, FIELD_BINDING_FLAGS).FieldType;
                var clip = _clipProp.objectReferenceValue;

                var guiContent = EditorGUIUtility.ObjectContent(clip, type);

                EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Fake ObjectField Button");

                var style = new GUIStyle("TextField");
                style.fixedHeight   = 16;
                style.imagePosition = clip ? ImagePosition.ImageLeft : ImagePosition.TextOnly;


                if (GUILayout.Button(guiContent, style ) && clip)
                    EditorGUIUtility.PingObject(clip);

                EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            }

            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The object can not be dragged in / change due to `EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);`. I voted up your solution though I still don't like that in this way there is only the name of the object displayed .. not the type ... it doesn't really work e.g. for Images etc (AudioClip was only one example). I'ld really prefer just to cut off the picker from the object field. But ofcourse thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @derHugo I've just updated the answer. Now the style looks more like the original `ObjectField`. A type icon is added and the type name for a `null` value is fetched from the field type info.

Comment: sorry until now I come to test it. Unfortunately I get an `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ObjectField' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?` for the line `private ObjectField m_ObjectField;` and `using UnityEditor.Experimental.UIElements;` is never used

Comment: Actually `ObjectField` is declared in `UnityEditor.Experimental.UIElements`. Many classes in experimental libraries are recently introduced. Which Unity3D version do you use?

Comment: I currently use 2017.3.1p4

Comment: My example has been tested on 2018.1.3f1. There might be an `ObjectField` class in another assembly in older versions. Can your editor lookup for declarations in assemblies, i.e. auto add references?

Comment: I use VisualStudio 2017 + ReSharper so yes usually it is capable of it

Comment: Hey dude , very sorry for coming back so late! I actually simply removed the line `private ObjectField m_ObjectField;` since it is never used later. Now it actually works perfect and looks nice ;)

Comment: Oh yes, this was a relic from editing, not used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've got another solution: **Ignore the pick result of this object picker**, and although the picker is still here and can show the picker window, pick up will not work.

(I still don't know how to hide this button and the pickerwindow, > <), and this answer was posted at unity answers as well.

Here is the code:

```
     // Register another callback of this object field
     myObjectField.RegisterValueChangedCallback(DefaultObjectFieldCallback);
     
     // In this callback, is a trick
     private void DefaultAssetFieldCallback(ChangeEvent<UnityEngine.Object> evt) {
         // unregister the callback first
         myObjectField.UnregisterValueChangedCallback(DefaultAssetFieldCallback);
     
         // trick: set back to the old value
         m_ConfigAssetField.value = evt.previousValue;
     
         // register the callback again
         myObjectField.RegisterValueChangedCallback(DefaultObjectFieldCallback);
     }
```

Comment: Yeah of course that's a nice info ... but the question was how to hide it, not how to ignore it's result ;) As you can see in the question code I already used `EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true)` to disable the entire field anyway so it isn't even clickable ;)

Comment: Yes, your solution is quite helpful! In fact, my colleagues wanted to disable the picker, but still keep the "ping" function, so I finally provided this trick XD

Comment: The accepted answer uses a button which still allows the ping functionality ;) That's why accepted it. In my specific use case as mentioned I wanted to make the field higher which just looks stupid because the Object picker gets also stretched and looks hilarious ^^ also I got users who still tried to click it even when it was notably disabled ^^ that's why we decided to not display it at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar and found a way to do this by stepping through the ObjectField in the UIToolkit Debugger. The type of the little object selector button is hidden, so we cant really work with the class itself.

This solution is using UIToolkit, so unfortunately it won't work with Unity Editor IMGUI, but hopefully it will be helpful to someone.

The Solution in easy steps:

1. Find out what the uss style class of the ObjectFieldSelector is.
2. Recursively search the children of the ObjectField for a VisualElement containing the uss style class.
3. Set visibility to false.
   All done!

```
    using UnityEditor;
    using UnityEditor.UIElements;
    using UnityEngine.UIElements;

    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(MyClass))]
    public class MyClassDrawer: PropertyDrawer
    {
        public override VisualElement CreatePropertyGUI(SerializedProperty property)
        {
            var field = new ObjectField(property.displayName);
            field.objectType = typeof(MyClass);

            var button = FindChild(field, "unity-object-field__selector");
            button.visible = false;

            return field;
        }

        private VisualElement FindChild(VisualElement parent, string ussClass)
        {
            foreach(var child in parent.Children())
            {
                if (child.ClassListContains(ussClass))
                    return child;

                var subChild = FindChild(child, ussClass);
                if (subChild != null)
                    return subChild;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. Tried a little more work to make it more like the unity built-in one.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

static partial class EditorGUIUtils {

    public static void ObjectDisplayFieldLayout(Object obj, params GUILayoutOption[] options) =>
        ObjectDisplayFieldLayout(obj, (GUIContent)null, options);

    public static void ObjectDisplayFieldLayout(Object obj, string label, params GUILayoutOption[] options) =>
        ObjectDisplayFieldLayout(obj, new GUIContent(label), options);

    public static void ObjectDisplayFieldLayout(Object obj, GUIContent label, params GUILayoutOption[] options) {

        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
        GUILayout.Space(2);
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Space(2);

        GUILayout.Space(EditorGUI.indentLevel * 15);

        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.textField);
        style.fixedHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
        style.imagePosition = obj != null ? ImagePosition.ImageLeft : ImagePosition.TextOnly;
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleLeft;

        GUIContent content = EditorGUIUtility.ObjectContent(obj, obj.GetType());

        Rect rect = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(4, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight, options);
        Rect objRect = rect;
        if (label != null) {
            Rect labelRect = rect;
            labelRect.width = rect.width / 2f - 1f;
            if (labelRect.width >= 1f) {
                EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(labelRect, label);
                objRect = labelRect;
                objRect.x = labelRect.xMax + 2f;
                objRect.width = Mathf.Max(4f, rect.xMax - objRect.x);
            }
        }

        var e = Event.current;
        if (e.type == EventType.MouseDown && e.button == 0 && objRect.Contains(e.mousePosition)) {
            if (obj != null)
                EditorGUIUtility.PingObject(obj);
            e.Use();
        }

        GUI.Button(objRect, content, style);

        GUILayout.Space(1);
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Space(1);
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
    }
}
```

Use it like

```
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Base Texture Reference", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
    if (BaseTextureList.arraySize <= 0) {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("not exist", EditorStyles.miniLabel);
    }
    else {
        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
        for (int i = 0; i < BaseTextureList.arraySize; i++) {
            EditorGUIUtils.ObjectDisplayFieldLayout(BaseTextureList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).objectReferenceValue, $"Texture {i}");
        }
        EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
    }
```